# Java 8 Stream API :How to handle null value in Map

Tags: java, dictionary, filter, java-stream

I have an arraylist of Map type . I want to filter out null values from the list and find max and min values. The program is working fine except for null values.

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Float>> elements = new ArrayList<Map<String, Float>>();
Map<String, Float> element = new HashMap<String, Float>();
element.put("a", (float) 1.22);
element.put("b", (float) 1.33);
element.put("c", (float) 1.52);
element.put("d", (float) 1.452);
element.put("e", (float) 1.452);

Map<String, Float> element2 = new HashMap<String, Float>();
element2.put("a", (float) 1.2332);
element2.put("b", (float) 1.242);
element2.put("c", (float) 1.552);
element2.put("d", (float) 15.33);
element2.put("e",null);

elements.add(element);
elements.add(element1);
elements.add(element2);

System.out.println("Initial Mappings are: " + elements);
Map<String, Float> min = elements.stream() 
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Math::min));

System.out.println(min);
```

Comment: null map or a null element in a map? Your example does not contain any nulls

Comment: You must try and ensure that your `Map` doesn't allow `null` writes such as `element2.put("e",null);` in reality. This was corrected in JDK itself with `Map.of`implementation in Java-9 as well.

Answer (score 5):

Add a filter to the chain.

```
Map<String, Float> min = elements.stream()
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Math::min));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` to filter null values and use [Collectors.summarizingDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) to get `min`,`max` and `average`

```
Map<String, DoubleSummaryStatistics> res = elements.stream() 
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .filter(entry->Objects.nonNull(entry.getValue()) // check for null value
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.summarizingDouble(entry->entry.getValue())));

res.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("Key : "+k+", Min : "+v.getMin()+", Max : "+v.getMax()));
```

Comment: The question doesn't really focus around using `**SummaryStatistics`, but a good suggestion, though the actual answer [already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59463706/1746118).